# Submit ASP.NET forms in parallel

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to submit one form multiple times in parallel. The server accepts the parameter `_ASYNCPOST`.

I can explain in an abstract way how the page works

1. Login
2. Submit form search (`POST`)
3. POST same form with new data (all these need to be done in parallel)

In the last step, I **yield** all the requests with every parameter I could find (including `__VIEWSTATE`, `EVENTTARGET`, etc)

The problem is that the first post works, but the rest return an error saying "The server data does not match the browser data, hit refresh"

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

I followed this doc https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition/

Comment: *"Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?"* - Not if the website you're using explicitly prevents it, which sounds plausible given the description.  If they are providing a random one-time-use token with each page request, then you'll need to examine the response to get the token before making the next request.

Comment: Then how could I handle this? Should I load one listing page in parallel before doing the form submission?

Comment: How you handle it depends on what the target site supports/does.  You'll need to continue to reverse engineer their site in order to replicate a permitted workflow of requests/responses.  If you're sending what you think should be correct requests and their site is responding with an error or unexpected results, your next step would be to report that problem to that site.

Comment: I agree that replicating user's workflow is the way to make it work, but it is not efficient for my specific case. I appreciate the help.